# How to ignore SSL issues in axios using React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, https, axios, expo

Hi I'm currently working with react native on Android with Expo. I am trying to send requests to my server which has a valid ssl certificate, but for some reason axios takes it as invalid, so axios does not allow me to send requests to my server's api.

this is the error i get:

`Error: Network Error`

So I wonder if there is any way to make axios ignore the problem with the ssl and can send the requests in a normal way

this is my code:

```
  try {
        const headers = {
            'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8',
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "application/json",
        };
        axios.get("https://URLtoMySERVER", {}, headers)
        .then(response => {
             console.log(response)
             const posts = response.data;
             console.log(posts)}
        ).catch(function(error) {
             console.log("error", error);
        });
 } catch (error) {
        console.log('err', error);
   }
```

some points that I want to clarify:

1- I can't use RNFetchBlob because I'm using Expo, and RNFetchBlob  have some native libraries.

2- I can't use httpsAgent either with axios because apparently https library does not work with expo, or at least it does not work for me.

3- fetch doesn't work either

Is there any other alternative to axios or fetch that works in react native with expo and where you can ignore the problems of https?

Comment: make sure your server is up and running.I have phase this type of error where my app is not connected with server for that my axios request return Error: Network Error

Comment: @Prakash Karena yes, I already made sure that my server works, with postman and insomnia the requests work well

Comment: your server is in local or production ?

Comment: my server is in Production

Comment: Is there a solution for this? I'm getting the same error. Tks.

Comment: @Alexandros did you find solution? Same issue i am also facing in my react-native axios code.

Comment: I had to change the ssl certificate, the letsencrypt certificate works